# Recent files history R

Tags: rstudio, recent-file-list

How can one find an extensive list of R files that were opened in RStudio? Sort of like the list under `File` -> `Recent Files` but much longer?

Comment: Removed the `r` tag, since it is specific to Rstudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe so. Per [this question](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200650543-File-history-and-project-history-stored-in-LOCALAPPDATA), it appears that the file history is stored locally at `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\monitored\lists\file_mru`. (Assuming Windows) When I looked at this file on my local machine, it simply matched the recent files I was seeing in RStudio. When I deleted a couple lines from the `file_mru` file, they also disappeared from RStudio.

However, given that they are stored in a text file, one could probably write some code to grab and store those filenames permanently, should you choose. Just doesn't appear that RStudio does that.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. Any idea for how to do it on the MacBook?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't. I only have access to a Windows machine, so I'm afraid I don't know that answer.

Comment: Under Linux it's at `~/.local/share/rstudio/monitored/lists/file_mru`, maybe that also help for Mac, as an originally *nix based system?